# Associativity equation for topological rings and logarithms

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, functional-equations, topological-rings

Let $R$ be a topological ring of characteristic zero. Assume that $R$ is commutative. Let $G :R \times R \to R$ be a continuous function satisfying $G(G(x,y),z)=G(x,G(y,z))$ and $G(0,x)=x$, for all $x,y,z \in R$.

If we assume that $G$ is a convergent power series then $G$ is also a formal group law and the Honda's argument(cf. Hazewinkel, "Formal Groups and Applications", Chapter 1, 5.8, p.37) proves that G admits a logarithm, i.e. $G(x,y)=h^{-1}(h(x)+h(y))$.

**Question :** Does $G$ admit a logarithm if it is only continuous?

**EDIT** Assuming that $G$ is continuous, what are the additional assumptions that should be made on $R$ and $G$ to guarantee the existence of logarithms?

Comment: But if $G$ is only continuous then the ring structure plays no rôle at all

Comment: As @მამუკაჯიბლაძე says: If $R $ has the discrete topology, then continuity means nothing, and we are just requiring that $G $ is a binary operation that makes $R $ a semigroup with left identity $0$. Such operations exist in abundance; not all of them are groups, so not all of them have logarithms.

Comment: What about $R=Q_p$?

Comment: For $Q_p$ you get arbitrary topological semigroup structure on the Cantor set with a point removed.